# How to make shortcuts

Tags: shortcuts

I have been using linux for a like a month and I have felt in love with it, so I as wondering if we can make shortcuts like in windows?

Comment: I guess this is for desktop shortcuts, not symbolic links. I might be wrong, though.

Comment: What shortcuts are you talking about? keyboard shortcuts or program shortcuts? or folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make shortcuts for folders by running the below command,

```
ln -s /path/to/the/original/directory /path/to/the/directorry/in/which/you/want/to/put/the/shortcut/file
```

Example,

```
ln -s ~/Pictures ~/Desktop
```

It will create shortcut for Pictures directory on your Desktop.

Comment: Thank you, also could you let me know what ~ means?

Comment: `~` is a shortcut for `/home/$USER`.

Answer (score 1):

Just 'right-click' on the folder you want to make a shortcut (called link in ubuntu) for, say Pictures folder, and select "make link". It will create another icon called 'link to Pictures' which you can now cut and paste somewhere else.

Comment: Ohhh that's why, I for it was something else, but yeah link makes sense. Thank you :)